# Does RDS on Windows Server 2008 R2 have a default max bandwidth per user?

Tags: bandwidth, rds

Is there a default max bandwidth limit on users of RDS Host in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: This needs clarification.  Limit *what* bandwidth?  The bandwidth used by the RDP session?  The bandwidth allocated to websurfing from with in the session?  The bandwidth allocated to file transfers?  The sum total of everything?  Etc.  Please update your question with that information, and respond to my comment so I can remove my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

The default is to accept whatever quality settings the client specifies when they make the connection. This can be configured via Group Policy (as always) for finer granularity, but the default is full-bore.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way that I know of to directly control or throttle the bandwidth used by an RDP client in an RDP session.

You can limit the color depth and disable printer, drive , audio and video, and device redirection to conserve the bandwidth used by the session.